# How to make bootstrap image and div expand to width of browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap layout here, so I would like to find out, how can I make the image background stretch 100% wide and the grey div color stretch 100% wide as well?

I am not sure if I should be using container fluid or not? Any ideas will be a big help. Thank you.

An image depicting what I am trying to go for:

[image]

And what I have so far in this snippet (go full screen to see):

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.heading {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  margin-top: -300px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.profile-info-right-top {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.profile-info-right-top img {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.user-profile {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.profile-header-background {
  margin: 0 -30px 0 -30px;
}
.profile-header-background img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
.profile-info-left {
  position: relative;
  top: -180px;
}
.profile-info-left img.avatar {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.profile-info-left h2 {
  font-family: "josefinslab-semibold";
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.profile-info-left .section {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.profile-info-left .section h3 {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.profile-info-left ul.list-social > li {
  line-height: 2.3;
}
.profile-info-left ul.list-social > li i {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  *vertical-align: auto;
  *zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  font-size: 16px;
  min-width: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
}
.profile-info-left ul.list-social > li a {
  color: #696565;
}
.profile-info-right .tab-content {
  padding: 30px 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .profile-info-right-top {
    position: relative;
    top: -160px;
  }
  .profile-info-right {
    position: relative;
    top: -160px;
  }
}
.user-follower,
.user-following {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.user-follower img,
.user-following img {
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 40px;
}
.user-follower a,
.user-following a {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1;
}
.user-follower .username,
.user-following .username {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.user-follower .btn,
.user-following .btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-width: 92px;
}
.btn-toggle-following {
  background-color: #7bae16;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn-toggle-following:hover {
  background-color: #ef2020;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn-toggle-following:hover span {
  display: none;
}
.btn-toggle-following:hover:after {
  content: 'Unfollow';
  display: inline;
}
.btn-toggle-following:hover i:before {
  content: '\f129';
}
/* list icons */

.list-icons-demo li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.list-icons-demo li i {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.list-icons-demo2 li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.activity-item {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px 0;
  border-top: 1px dashed #ccc;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.activity-item:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}
.activity-item .avatar {
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 32px;
}
.activity-item > i {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1;
}
.activity-item .media-body {
  position: relative;
}
.activity-item .activity-title {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 1.3;
}
.activity-item .activity-attachment {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.activity-item .well {
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  border-left: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 0.85em;
}
.activity-item .thumbnail {
  display: inline;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.activity-item .thumbnail img {
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
}
.activity-item .activity-actions {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 0;
}
.activity-item .activity-actions .btn i {
  margin: 0;
}
.activity-item .activity-actions .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
.activity-item + .btn {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a {
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 2px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 2px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
}
.nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-pills > li > a {
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.nav-pills > li.active > a,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
  background-color: #1688ae;
}
.nav-tabs.tabs-iconized > li a,
.nav-pills.tabs-iconized > li a {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.nav-tabs.tabs-iconized > li i,
.nav-pills.tabs-iconized > li i {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 3px;
  top: 4px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.tab-content {
  padding: 30px 15px 15px 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.nav.nav-tabs-custom-colored > li > a {
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-bottom: transparent;
}
.nav.nav-tabs-custom-colored > li > a:hover,
.nav.nav-tabs-custom-colored > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #1688ae;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-tabs-custom-colored {
  border-bottom-color: #1688ae;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-tabs-custom-colored > li {
  z-index: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-tabs-custom-colored > li > a {
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 2px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 2px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  color: #696565;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-tabs-custom-colored > li > a:hover,
.nav-tabs.nav-tabs-custom-colored > li > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #1688ae;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-tabs-custom-colored > li.active > a,
.nav-tabs.nav-tabs-custom-colored > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs.nav-tabs-custom-colored > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1688ae;
  border-color: #1688ae;
  border-bottom: transparent;
}
.nav-tabs > li.active {
  z-index: 1;
}
.nav-pills-custom-minimal {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.nav-pills-custom-minimal > li > a {
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
  color: #696565;
}
.nav-pills-custom-minimal > li > a:hover,
.nav-pills-custom-minimal > li > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #4f4c4c;
}
.nav-pills-custom-minimal > li.active > a,
.nav-pills-custom-minimal > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-pills-custom-minimal > li.active > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: #94c632;
  color: #696565;
}
.nav-pills-custom-minimal > li + li {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .nav-pills-custom-minimal > li + li {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
.nav-pills-custom-minimal.custom-minimal-bottom > li a {
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
}
.nav-pills-custom-minimal.custom-minimal-bottom > li.active > a,
.nav-pills-custom-minimal.custom-minimal-bottom > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-pills-custom-minimal.custom-minimal-bottom > li.active > a:focus {
  border-bottom-color: #94c632;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="user-profile">
    <div class="profile-header-background">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/1000/400" alt="Profile Header Background">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 heading">
        <h2>User name</h2>
        <span>title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="profile-info-left">
          <div class="text-left">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/310/400" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
          </div>
          <div class="action-buttons">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><i class="fa fa-plus-round"></i> Follow</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"><i class="fa fa-android-mail"></i> Message</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="section">
            <h3>About</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="clearfix profile-info-right-top">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="profile-info-right">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-custom-minimal custom-minimal-bottom">
            <li class="active"><a href="#activities" data-toggle="tab">HEADING</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#followers" data-toggle="tab">HEADING</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#following" data-toggle="tab">HEADING</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="tab-content">
            <!-- activities -->
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="activities">
              <div class="media activity-item">
                <a href="#" class="pull-left">
                  <img src="http://placekitten.com/20/20" alt="Avatar" class="media-object avatar">
                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                  <p class="activity-title"><a href="#">Antonius</a> started following <a href="#">Jack Bay</a>  <small class="text-muted">- 2m ago</small>
                  </p>
                  <small class="text-muted">Today 08:30 am - 02.05.2014</small>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group pull-right activity-actions">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">I don't want to see this</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Unfollow Antonius</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Get Notification</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="media activity-item">
                <a href="#" class="pull-left">
                  <img src="http://placekitten.com/20/20" alt="Avatar" class="media-object avatar">
                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                  <p class="activity-title"><a href="#">Jane Doe</a> likes <a href="#">Jack Bay</a>  <small class="text-muted">- 36m ago</small>
                  </p>
                  <small class="text-muted">Today 07:23 am - 02.05.2014</small>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group pull-right activity-actions">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">I don't want to see this</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Unfollow Jane Doe</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Get Notification</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="media activity-item">
                <a href="#" class="pull-left">
                  <img src="http://placekitten.com/20/20" alt="Avatar" class="media-object avatar">
                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                  <p class="activity-title"><a href="#">Michael</a> posted something for <a href="#">Jack Bay</a>  <small class="text-muted">- 1h ago</small>
                  </p>
                  <small class="text-muted">Today 07:23 am - 02.05.2014</small>
                  <div class="activity-attachment">
                    <div class="well well-sm">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group pull-right activity-actions">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">I don't want to see this</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Unfollow Michael</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Get Notification</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="media activity-item">
                <a href="#" class="pull-left">
                  <img src="http://placekitten.com/20/20" alt="Avatar" class="media-object avatar">
                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                  <p class="activity-title"><a href="#">Jack Bay</a> has uploaded two photos <small class="text-muted">- Yesterday</small>
                  </p>
                  <small class="text-muted">Yesterday 06:42 pm - 01.05.2014</small>
                  <div class="activity-attachment">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                          <img src="http://placekitten.com/210/210" alt="Uploaded photo">
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group pull-right activity-actions">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">I don't want to see this</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Unfollow Jack Bay</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Get Notification</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="media activity-item">
                <a href="#" class="pull-left">
                  <img src="http://placekitten.com/20/20" alt="Avatar" class="media-object avatar">
                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                  <p class="activity-title"><a href="#">Jack Bay</a> has changed his profile picture <small class="text-muted">- 2 days ago</small>
                  </p>
                  <small class="text-muted">2 days ago 05:42 pm - 30.04.2014</small>
                  <div class="activity-attachment">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                      <img src="http://placekitten.com/210/210" alt="Uploaded photo">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group pull-right activity-actions">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">I don't want to see this</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Unfollow Jack Bay</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Get Notification</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default center-block"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Load more activities</button>
            </div>
            <!-- end activities -->
            <!-- followers -->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="followers">
              <div class="media user-follower">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/20/20" alt="User Avatar" class="media-object pull-left">
                <div class="media-body">
                  <a href="#">Antonius<br><span class="text-muted username">@mrantonius</span></a>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-toggle-following pull-right"><i class="fa fa-checkmark-round"></i>  <span>Following</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="media user-follower">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/20/20" alt="User Avatar" class="media-object pull-left">
                <div class="media-body">
                  <a href="#">Michael<br><span class="text-muted username">@iamichael</span></a>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Follow</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="media user-follower">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/20/20" alt="User Avatar" class="media-object pull-left">
                <div class="media-body">
                  <a href="#">Stella<br><span class="text-muted username">@stella</span></a>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Follow</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="media user-follower">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/20/20" alt="User Avatar" class="media-object pull-left">
                <div class="media-body">
                  <a href="#">Jane Doe<br><span class="text-muted username">@janed</span></a>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-toggle-following pull-right"><i class="fa fa-checkmark-round"></i>  <span>Following</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="media user-follower">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/20/20" alt="User Avatar" class="media-object pull-left">
                <div class="media-body">
                  <a href="#">John Simmons<br><span class="text-muted username">@jsimm</span></a>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Follow</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="media user-follower">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/20/20" alt="User Avatar" class="media-object pull-left">
                <div class="media-body">
                  <a href="#">Antonius<br><span class="text-muted username">@mrantonius</span></a>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-toggle-following pull-right"><i class="fa fa-checkmark-round"></i>  <span>Following</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="media user-follower">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/20/20" alt="User Avatar" class="media-object pull-left">
                <div class="media-body">
                  <a href="#">Michael<br><span class="text-muted username">@iamichael</span></a>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Follow</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="media user-follower">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/20/20" alt="User Avatar" class="media-object pull-left">
                <div class="media-body">
                  <a href="#">Stella<br><span class="text-muted username">@stella</span></a>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Follow</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="media user-follower">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/20/20" alt="User Avatar" class="media-object pull-left">
                <div class="media-body">
                  <a href="#">Jane Doe<br><span class="text-muted username">@janed</span></a>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-toggle-following pull-right"><i class="fa fa-checkmark-round"></i>  <span>Following</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="media user-follower">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/20/20" alt="User Avatar" class="media-object pull-left">
                <div class="media-body">
                  <a href="#">John Simmons<br><span class="text-muted username">@jsimm</span></a>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Follow</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end followers -->
            <!-- following -->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="following">
              <div class="media user-following">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/20/20" alt="User Avatar" class="media-object pull-left">
                <div class="media-body">
                  <a href="#">Stella<br><span class="text-muted username">@stella</span></a>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right"><i class="fa fa-close-round"></i> Unfollow</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="media user-following">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/20/20" alt="User Avatar" class="media-object pull-left">
                <div class="media-body">
                  <a href="#">Jane Doe<br><span class="text-muted username">@janed</span></a>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right"><i class="fa fa-close-round"></i> Unfollow</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="media user-following">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/20/20" alt="User Avatar" class="media-object pull-left">
                <div class="media-body">
                  <a href="#">John Simmons<br><span class="text-muted username">@jsimm</span></a>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right"><i class="fa fa-close-round"></i> Unfollow</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="media user-following">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/20/20" alt="User Avatar" class="media-object pull-left">
                <div class="media-body">
                  <a href="#">Antonius<br><span class="text-muted username">@mrantonius</span></a>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right"><i class="fa fa-close-round"></i> Unfollow</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="media user-following">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/20/20" alt="User Avatar" class="media-object pull-left">
                <div class="media-body">
                  <a href="#">Michael<br><span class="text-muted username">@iamichael</span></a>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right"><i class="fa fa-close-round"></i> Unfollow</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="media user-following">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/20/20" alt="User Avatar" class="media-object pull-left">
                <div class="media-body">
                  <a href="#">Stella<br><span class="text-muted username">@stella</span></a>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right"><i class="fa fa-close-round"></i> Unfollow</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your main header image and the thumbnails out of a the `.container` class since you do not wish to restrict their widths at various viewport sizes, which is what `.container` does.

So the pseudo code would be:

```
<header>
  <img>
  <thumbnails>
</header>
<main>
  <leftcolumn>
    <img>
  </leftcolumn>
  <rightcolumn>
    <text>
    <text>
  </rightcolumn>
</main>
```

To keep the thumbnails in-line with the image and content in the main body you will need to replicate the `.col-md-**` classes you used in the main body around the thumbnails.

Since you want to overlap content I would add a negative margin to the left column to pull it up and over the header content.

Below is some basic markup to demonstrate my suggested approach.

```css
header .primary-img {
  width: 100%;
}
.img-list {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.img-list ul,
.img-list li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.img-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1.5rem 0.5rem;
}
.content {
  margin: 50px 0;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .content .left {
    margin-top: -225px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header class="primary-header">
  <img class="primary-img" src="http://placehold.it/1200x400">
  <div class="img-list">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=1">
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=2">
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=3">
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=4">
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<main class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="left col-md-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x400/ffcc00">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <p>
          Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here.
        </p>
        <p>
          Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here.
        </p>
        <p>
          Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

**Note:** Notice I took into account how to handle smaller screens where overlapping the image probably won't workout and would need to move it.

#### Edit

Per the comments below I have added a solution to moving the avatar image.

If all you need to do is move the avatar img from one region to another, the simplest thing to do might be to include it in the markup where you need it twice. Then use media queries to hide/show the appropriate avatar for the screen size.

I made each image a different color so you can easily identify the switch.

```css
header .primary-img {
  width: 100%;
}
.img-list {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.img-list ul,
.img-list li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.img-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1.5rem 0.5rem;
}
.content {
  margin: 50px 0;
}
.sidebar-avatar {
  display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .header-avatar {
    display: none;
  }
  .sidebar-avatar {
    display: block;
  }
  .content .left {
    margin-top: -225px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header class="primary-header">
  <img class="primary-img" src="http://placehold.it/1200x400">
  <div class="header-avatar">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x400/ffcc00?text=avatar+1">
  </div>
  <div class="img-list">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=1">
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=2">
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=3">
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=4">
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<main class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="left col-md-4">
        <div class="sidebar-avatar">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x400/A3D76F?text=avatar+2">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <p>
          Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here.
        </p>
        <p>
          Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here.
        </p>
        <p>
          Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: this is near perfect! how could I make the grey div with the images fall below the avatar though? Is that simple to achieve?

Comment: Below the yellow image in my demo (on smaller screens)?

Comment: What about the content below that image? Where does that go in relation to the content to the right of the image?

Comment: ok, so on smaller screens it should try to go like this: the avatar first, then the grey div of images, and the content to the right below it. Could this be achieved? I had the idea like my original snippet for smaller screens showed...

Comment: did that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I added a new snippet below the original. Not sure where the content below the avatar is supposed to go. I made each avatar image a different color so you can easily see it switching.

Comment: thanks for this, you have helped me out a lot. So the green avatar (in smaller screen), I can simply add a negative padding to push it up over the header image like the yellow avatar is, right?

Comment: The yellow one is displayed for smaller screens. You would use a negative margin (not padding) just like the yellow image in order to overlap. Though you might have to make your large header a set height as setting a fixed negative margin might overlap more of the large header image than you want.

Comment: just another issue. Is it possible to have some side content under the green avatar but also display it before the main content? I cant seem see the side content at all in smaller screens...

Answer (score 0):

I don't get exactly what are you trying to do and how to fix it, but for the nature of your css and the image you are trying to replicate, I think you should make use of the next properties:

- [Background Image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) (for manipulating the image as a background and not as an img tag)
- [Background Position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) (for positioning the image in the center)
- [Background Repeat](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp) (the 'no-repeat' value let you cover the background with a single image)
- [Background Size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) (the 'cover' value could be useful to cover all the background of the element so it can have 100% of the width of its element)

I think [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp) would be pretty useful too.

Please, tell us if we can provide any additional help.

Comment: Diaz Allan I am actually trying to do whats in the image I have provided first. To make the image div and the grey div stretch 100% width of the browser..

Answer (score 0):

Move:-

```
<div class="profile-header-background">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/1000/400" alt="Profile Header Background">
</div>
<div class="clearfix profile-info-right-top">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30">

      </div>
    </div>
```

Above the container class.

You will need to fix the contents of col-md-12 though.

Answer (score 0):

For the image and grey div you should use a wrapper around a container. Don't use container-fluid since your main column structure will be messed up. Try adding another div around your container and give this div a background image/color.

For your background image use the following code:

```
<div class="profile-header-background">
</div>
<div class="grey-div">
   <div class="container grey-container">
      ..place your grey content here..
   </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  ..place your content here..
</div>
```

With following CSS:

```
.profile-header-background {
   height: 400px;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
   background-image: url('http://placecage.com/1000/400');
   width: 100%;
}
.grey-div {
   background: grey;
}
```

Since you are using `margin-top: -300px` you can simply place your container outside and after the background image.

Comment: what about the grey div that I want 100% wide as well? Should I put it outside the container as well under the profile-header?

Comment: Added grey div also, see answer @Krystyna. Yes you should